# stack size by user

Tags: c++, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to have my stack be dynamically allocated based on the number of letters a user inputs.

My current program gets a set of letters or numbers then output them in FILO order (thus reverse order).

For example, if a user inputs 123, it sets the size of stack to 3 and returns 321.

This is my header (class)

```
class CharStack {
    enum {size = 100};      //size of stack. big enough to receive long letters.
    int top;                //top pointer 
    char buf[size];         //stack's size

    public:

    CharStack()             //constructor
        {top = size;}

    bool chkEmpty() const   //true if no data in stack
        {return top == size;}
    bool chkFull() const    //true if stack is full
        {return !top;}
    bool push(char ch);     //pop data from stack
    char pop();
};
```

and this is my main.

```
int main()  {
    CharStack chStack;              //A stack with 100
    char str[100];
    int *size;

    cout << "input letter or numbers:";
    cin >> str;
    size = new int[strlen(str)+1];  //count number of letters.
```

and so on...

I think all I need to do from here is to set `size (in main) =  buf[size]` (in the header file).  I believe there's a very simple way to solve this, but I just don't see it.

Comment: FIFO means elements come out in the same order as they went in, not reversed.   In any event, to answer your question, `size` is a `private` member of `CharStack`, so is not accessible to `main()` in your code.   If you need to access the value of something that is private, declare a `public` member function of the class which returns it.

Comment: FIFO: first in first out, taht doesn't revert.

Comment: You know std::stack?

Comment: thanks for all the comments.  I've just edited FIFO to FILO.  I will do googling on std::stack.

Comment: FILO ist named LIFO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stack<char>` which does what you need.

However, if you must or want to do it yourself, you should make `buf` a pointer to char and allocate and deallocate memory as needed with `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Similar to what is done in your code with `size`.  Using `std::vector<char>` is an in-between solution.

You can pass the size to your class via the constructor or a `setSize()` function.